# offline image search in java

Tags: java, image, search, ocr

I want to create an application that can search images using strings i.e. if i enter a string it shows all the images containing that string. I already have created an OCR engine using java. So now, can i extend that engine further for search or is there some other library available for image search. Also, if i want to extend the OCR engine how should i take the step ahead? 
i have tried searching for [lucene](http://www.lire-project.net/) but i can't understand. Any suggestions would help. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search images using keywords you need to tag them first. You can use you OCR retrieved text to start with.

As search engine, I would use solar. You can easily add text snippets using the update mechanism.